# Django Rest-Framework `ImproperlyConfigured - Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "<model>:detail"`

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I have this exception when I try to access to the endpoint named `/clients/` :

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "client-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

I have tried a lot of solutions seen online, but no one works :

[Django Rest Framework - Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "user-detail"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20550598/django-rest-framework-could-not-resolve-url-for-hyperlinked-relationship-using)

[Django Rest Framework, improperly configured lookup field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55102004/django-rest-framework-improperly-configured-lookup-field)

[You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71312665/you-may-have-failed-to-include-the-related-model-in-your-api-or-incorrectly-con)

[DRF Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name on PrimaryKeyRelatedField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65440636/drf-could-not-resolve-url-for-hyperlinked-relationship-using-view-name-on-primar)

For the context, each client is a user (django user) and to know if a user is a client, it has to be in the table client in my database.
So I want when I use the endpoint `/clients/` to have informations about the user linked to
the client (I use this system because I will have two types of user, the 2th isn't created yet).

There is my code :

**user/models.py :**

```py
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migration = True

    def create_user(self, mail, name, lastname, password=None):
        if not name or not lastname or not mail:
            raise ValueError("y pas tout")
        user = self.model(mail=self.normalize_email(mail), lastname=lastname, name=name)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_staffuser(self, mail, name, lastname, password):
        user = self.create_user(mail, name, lastname, password=password)
        user.staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, mail, name, lastname, password):
        user = self.create_user(mail, name, lastname, password=password)
        user.staff = True
        user.admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    mail = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    object = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'mail'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'lastname']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.mail

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.mail

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perm(self, app_label):
        return True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.mail

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_adin(self):
        return self.admin
```

**user/serializers.py :**

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'mail')
        lookup_field = 'username'
```

**user/views.py :**

```py
class UserViews(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.object.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'username'
```

**client/models.py :**

```py
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL


class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

    @property
    def user__username(self):
        return self.user.username

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**client/serializers.py :**

```py
class ClientSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(read_only=True, view_name='user-detail', lookup_field='username')

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        lookup_field = 'user__username'
        fields = ('url', 'user')
```

**client/views :**

```py
class ClientViewSets(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Client.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClientSerializer
    lookup_field = 'user__username'
```

**client/urls.py :**

```py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'clients', views.ClientViewSets, basename='client')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls))
]
```

**project/urls.py :**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(('client.urls', 'client'), namespace='client')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

Note : I import each time the *User* models via `from django.contrib.auth.models imposer User` except for the models class of client where I use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` adviced by Django.

Thanks in advance !